# Setting up a SOAP enviornment?

Tags: apache, tomcat, soap

I want to set up a SOAP development enviornment.  So I can create web services and such.  I tried following the docs for the TOMCAT/AXIS/APACHE stuff but it all seemed outdated?  Any recommendations, links or resources to good ways to set up an SOAP enviornment?  I will be using Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to decide on what container to use, [Apache Axis2](http://Aapche%20Axis2) is a popular choice. You can then go through the [QuickStart guide](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/quickstartguide.html) to get things up and running quickly. Another popular choice is [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/).

I know you favor eclipse, but [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) comes with some example web services packages installed.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to write your webservice in a development language such as PHP and have it served up to the consumer of your webservice with something like a webserver(apache)